# Google Calendar API only list single events of multiple dates

Tags: go, google-calendar-api

I'm using golang to get the list of events from the company calendar. But some of the item only return one when it supposed to return more than one.

For example, 10 Oct 2022 and 11 Oct 2022 are Sales Day. I want my script to return both of the items but it return only 10 Oct 2022. What did I miss here?

I have referred to this Doc https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list

Here is my code:

```
events, err := w.GCalendar.Calendar.Events.
        List(CALENDAR_ID).
        MaxResults(90).
        TimeMin(currentDate).
        TimeZone("Asia/Singapore").
        Do()
    if err != nil {
        w.Logger.Errorf("Unable to retrieve the user's events: %v", err)
    }

for _, item := range events.Items {
            date := item.Start.DateTime
            if date == "" {
                date = item.Start.Date
            }
            
            layout := "2006-01-02"
            dateTime, err := time.Parse(layout, date)
            formattedDate := dateTime.Format("02/Jan/06")

            if err != nil {
                w.Logger.Errorf("Parsing Time.err=%s", err.Error())
            }
            dateList = append(dateList, formattedDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

I manage to get the end date and calculate the total days of the events, then add those days to the start date.